# How to identify the session of the informix rollback?

Tags: informix

Im having IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC8W1XI and below error appeared in the online log. I need to know how to figure out session information which cause to below rollback

```
11:06:51  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:06:55  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:06:57  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:06:57  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:06:58  sprollback sqerrno -244 sqiserrno -7350
11:06:59  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:07:04  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:07:08  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:07:10  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:07:13  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:07:19  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:07:21  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
11:07:33  sprollback sqerrno -239 sqiserrno -100
```

Comment: Thanks for including the version information.  Please note that 11.70 is no longer officially supported, and hasn't been for some time.

Comment: My immediate reaction is "Informix doesn't normally use the terms sqerrno or sqiserrno, and I have been unable to find `sprollback` in the current code".  However, when I go back to the 11.70 code, I find the error message in one of the files related to HDR (replication). It is generated in a block of code related to constraint checking and savepoint commit/rollback operations, if the comments are to be believed. It is in code related to 'redirected writes for the primary server', which I think means that an update on the secondary node was transferred to the primary but failed on the primary.

Comment: Unless your company has an extended support contract, you are in a very difficult place.  I'm not sure what's best to recommend — I'm not an HDR/replication expert.  I suspect it means that your primary and secondary are seriously out of sync with each other.  I'm not sure how you'd do best resynchronizing them.  I suspect you'll end up having to rebuild the pair — choose one as being accurate and reestablish the HDR pair using that as the master.  You might need to break the pair, perform separate exports of the data, compare the results, and so on.  It is probably going to be painful.

Comment: If you have a support contract of any sort for Informix, you can try consulting with Tech Support about what's best to do.  But expect to run into problems because the system is unsupported.